# Swift4 : FMDBdatabase - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

Update:

> In the end, I go to the local SQLite database and replace the NULL value to
>   "unkown".  This works!

I am using FMDatabaseQueue to search an existing sqlite database in iOS.

```
//Data model
import Foundation
import UIKit
class scoreModel: NSObject {
    var lessonName:String = String()
    var lessonCode:String = String()
    var creditPoint:Double = Double()
    var totalStudentNumber:Int = Int()
    var teacherName:String = String()
    var semesterName:String = String()
    var scoreValue:String = String()
    var studentCount:Int = Int()
}
```

Unfortunately, there are some "" string in my database. Like:

```
teacherName "" 

scoreValue ""
```

[image: Image of error database in Xcode]

While searching, Xcode alerted that

```
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in line "teacherName".
```

[image: Image of error]

I don't need these "" results necessarily as they are not important. How can I  fix it?

```
func queryDB(sql: String) -> NSMutableArray {

    openDB ();
    let resultArray = NSMutableArray()

    SQLiteManager.shareInstance.dbQueue?.inDatabase { (db) in
        let dbResult: FMResultSet! = db.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsIn:[])

        if (dbResult != nil)
        {
            while dbResult.next() {
                let model:scoreModel = scoreModel()
                model.lessonName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "lessonName")!)
                model.lessonCode = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "lessonCode")!)
                model.creditPoint = Double(dbResult.double(forColumn: "creditPoint"))
                model.semesterName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "semesterName")!)
                model.teacherName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "teacherName")!)
                model.totalStudentNumber = Int(dbResult.int(forColumn: "totalStudentNumber"))
                model.scoreValue = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "scoreValue")!)
                model.studentCount = Int(dbResult.int(forColumn: "studentCount"))
                resultArray.add(model)
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `dbResult.string(forColumn: "teacherName")` is returning an optional with a nil value, so maybe this object had a nil value when you saved it. It doesn't really matter, what's important is how you want to treat objects that don't have all the fields that you're expecting. The question you need to ask yourself is "how should I handle the case where the thing in the database doesn't have a teacher name?" Here are two ideas:

In order to be considered "valid," everything in the database needs to have all the properties I'm expecting, otherwise I ignore it. That would look like this:

```
    while dbResult.next() {
        if let lessonName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "lessonName")),
        let lessonCode = String.dbResult.string(forColumn: "lessonCode")),
        let creditPoint = Double(dbResult.double(forColumn: "creditPoint")),
        let semesterName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "semesterName")),
        let teacherName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "teacherName")),
        let totalStudentNumber = Int(dbResult.int(forColumn: "totalStudentNumber")),
        let scoreValue = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "scoreValue")),
        let studentCount = Int(dbResult.int(forColumn: "studentCount")) {
            let model = scoreModel()
            model.lessonName = lessonName
            ...     // set lessonCode, etc
            resultArray.add(model)
        }
    }
```

Another choice is to provide default values using optional coalescing or similar.

```
while dbResult.next() {
    let lessonName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "lessonName")) ?? ""
    let lessonCode = String.dbResult.string(forColumn: "lessonCode")) ?? ""
    let creditPoint = Double(dbResult.double(forColumn: "creditPoint")) ?? ""
    let semesterName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "semesterName")) ?? ""
    let teacherName = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "teacherName")) ?? ""
    let totalStudentNumber = Int(dbResult.int(forColumn: "totalStudentNumber")) ?? 0
    let scoreValue = String(dbResult.string(forColumn: "scoreValue")) ?? ""
    let studentCount = Int(dbResult.int(forColumn: "studentCount")) ?? 0
    let model = scoreModel()
    model.lessonName = lessonName
    ...     // set lessonCode, etc
    resultArray.add(model)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your generous advice. In the end, I go to the Sqlite database and replace the NULL value to "unkown".

Comment: I don't know how to convert result to UTF8. Add utf8 in string seem didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "convert result to UTF8"? Which thing are you trying to convert?

Comment: the resultArray printed like this:
<model>:0x60000013edc0
<model>:0x60000013edc0
<model>:0x60000013edc0
<model>:0x60000013edc0
<model>:0x60000013edc0

Comment: I want it printed in Chinese, like:"高等数学C(下） MATH120006.01 4 70 29 杭国明 2010~2011学年第2学期 A 4"

Comment: Since your `ScoreModel` class inherits from `NSObject` you should be able to accomplish this by overriding `debugDescription()` and returning the string you'd like to appear. I believe my original reply answers your original question — if you agree would you mind marking it correct?

Comment: It's so sad. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.